# Apply filters after search with elastic search

Tags: java, filter, elasticsearch

I have the following use case scenario. I am doing a search with some query terms by aggregating some fields without applying any filters initially. Now let's say the results are 100,000 and I have 50,000 from class A and 50,000 from class B. In the UI if I click the class A button, I want to filter the results and show one the ones that belong to class A. Is this possible without doing a new search. Can I filter the results after the search is done. If yes how I can do it? Some java code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use post_filters. You can get check the official page [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html) for more information about that.

You can also read about filters work in the blog post [here](https://www.found.no/foundation/optimizing-elasticsearch-searches/).

This is mainly how filters work :

[image]

Comment: As I can see [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html#search) post filter is applied during the search request. I want to filter my data after this request. I want to filter the data from the SearchResponse.

Comment: Post filters are applied after the query is executed. It applies when the results are computed and then it filters on them.

Comment: The sample code in the link I posted shows that the setPostFilter() function is applied before the execute() function. From this I understand that the filters are applied before the query is executed. Can you give me an example in Java that shows the different? Thanks in advance

Comment: I already know that code sample. The execute() function just sends the query over the index. It doesn't actually executes it! elasticsearch does that! I just want to remind you that your java application is a client that sends request to the server elasticsearch to be executed. So actually the order of execution of your query will be as described in the blog post I have updated my answer with.